# Css parallax doesn't work

Tags: css, parallax

Hey guys I'm following the W3S tutorials and I want to archive the parallax effect. I've tried many times and I don't know why the picture doesn't show.
I did the exact same thing on another project and it worked just fine. I really don't know what I did wrong. My reputation it's kinda bad here because of my "stupid questions", so I'm sorry if this question offend someone.
Have a look at my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

#showcase {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/g/1900/1080?random');
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: top;
}

.button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.Bshadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.pacifont {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  color: white;
}

.name {
  color: #008c06;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  /* background-color: #333; */
  border-bottom: 3px solid #008c06;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #008c06;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/500/1081/?random'");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header id="showcase">
  <div class="topnav sticky" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
  <h1 class="pacifont">Welcome <a class="name">Felix!</a></h1>
  <a href="#" class="button Bshadow">READY?</a>
</header>
<a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/50d854d35/brussels/" data-label_1="Bruxelles" data-font="Jura" data-icons="Climacons Animated" data-days="3" data-theme="gray">Bruxelles</a>
<h1>wtf</h1>
<div class="parallax"></div>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus odit dolorum sed ut, doloremque consectetur.</p>
```

Comment: `position: top;` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the height of .parallax class to 100vh instead of 100%.

Comment: Thank you very much .Could you explain why the % doesn't work in that case?

Comment: When you assign height : 100% it takes to consider it's parent's height. In this case parrent of .parallax class is body and there is height assigned to it so it was not working. What you can do is assign body 100% also body's parent html 100 % and i will work.